# positiveness of degree 6,8,10,12 polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I would like to know if there is any method or way to check positiveness
in a degree 6,8,10 or 12 polynomial. I know that one can check the discriminant
for lower degrees, but I do not know if one can check it for higher degrees as
mentioned above.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, any polynomial of degree $6,8,10,12$ is a product of $3,4,5,6$ quadratic polynomials respectively...

Comment: @Qurultay That can't be right, it contradicts the Abel-Ruffini theorem.

Comment: @Qurultay Actually, you are of course right (the factorization is 'just' the fundamental theorem of algebra).  My comment doesn't apply because the coefficients of the quadratics can be complicated (ie not involve radicals).  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The easiest way is to construct a [Sturm sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for the given polynomial $p$ and to count the number of its real zeros as described there. Before applying this procedure, one could make sure that there are no multiple zeros by dividing      $p$ by the gcd of $p$ and $p'$. This  works for any degree